# Access Datagrid from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a simple WPF window with a Datagrid and an "Add" button. The add button is wired to the ViewModel using a RelayCommand, and basically just adds a new object to the observable collection and then sets the selected item (also databound from the grid's SelectedItem property). The end result is a new row is added to the grid and is then set to the selected row. This is *almost* the result I'm trying to achieve, because the next step is to put the grid in edit mode by invoking BeginEdit. The problem is, from my understanding, the VM isn't supposed to access controls on the view directly.
So my question is, what would be the most "correct" way of achieving this using MVVM?

Comment: Sounds like that's a UI-specific issue, so perhaps some code behind to ensure that the selected row in the grid is always in edit mode? I've always hated having to click twice on a grid row to edit it anyways. Alternatively, make some UI code for the SelectedItemChanged event so if selectedRow is new, BeginEdit

Comment: I hate the double click too, which is why I also have an "Edit" button but I faced the same problem with trying to put the code for it in the VM so I ended up using a classic code-behind event handler for it. Are you saying I should do the same for the SelectedItemChanged event (i.e. put the logic in the view)?

Comment: Well if its UI logic that the selected item should always be editable, then its fine in the code-behind. Or if it's UI logic that the selected item should always be editable if its a new record, that's fine in the code-behind too imo. Alternatively, I suppose you could try making a custom grid DependencyProperty that you bind to a property on the ViewModel, and whenever its set to true make sure the selected item in the grid is editable. Then from your ViewModel you'd just set IsEditable = true/false, and the custom DP would translate that to calling BeginEdit/EndEdit for you

Comment: How would I determine if the selectedRow is new? Would be nice if the datagrid had a row added event...